# How to add Controls programatically in titanium alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am trying to add controls programmatically in titanium alloy.
I did the fallowing code but it not working i don't know why??

XML

```
<Alloy>
  <Window class="container">
        <View id="TextOrders">
        <ScrollView id="scrollView" showVerticalScrollIndicator="true" showHorizontalScrollIndicator="true" >

        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Controller

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
var TextOrders = Ti.UI.createView({
  backgroundColor:'white'
});
function createRow(i) {
  var row = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: '#bbb',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width:'100%', height: 70,
    top: 0, left: 0
  });
  var inputTextField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    hintText: 'Enter value ' + i,
    keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION,
    top: 10, left: '10%',
    width: '80%', height: 60
  });
  row.add(inputTextField);
  return row;
}
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  bottom:120,
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  layout: 'vertical',
   backgroundColor: 'red',
   height:'58%'
});

for(var i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
    var row = createRow(i);
    scrollView.add(row);
}
TextOrders.add(scrollView);
```

tss

```
".container" : {
  backgroundColor:"white"
}
"#TextOrders":{
    width:'100%',
    height:'57%',
    borderColor:'red',
    borderWidth:'1px',
    top:'0px',
}
"#scrollView":{
    width:'80%',
    borderColor:'blue',
    borderWidth:'1px',
    top:'0px',
    height:'80%',
}
```

It does not giving me any error but controls is not getting added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextOrders.add(scrollView);`

should be:

`$.TextOrders.add(scrollView);`

Comment: But After adding controls i have to set the  scroll potion to bottom. I have gives the bottom :'0px' but it not working.

Comment: by "set the scroll position to bottom", I'm not sure if you want to scroll to the bottom (if so, check the scrollToBottom() function in the docs) or if you want the scrollView to appear at the bottom of the window.  Since you have the ScrollView added to a View, the bottom:0 will be relative to the height of the container View which I can see is 57% so it won't appear at the bottom of the main window.